# Reverse Proxy issue in Nginx Between 2 pcs' on same network one server with apache and other is node.js

Tags: php, node.js, apache, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to setup up functionality where if someone tries to hit <pc1 private IP>:7000 (php apache) it should be redirected to nodejs server on 127.0.0.1:3000 on pc2. For this, I set up nodejs server and nginx server on pc2. (In Windows)
Here is my nginx.conf file

```
server {
   listen       7000;
   server_name  <pc1 private IP>;

   location / {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
   }
}
```

Comment: If node.js server is running on pc2 then you'll have to IP of that pc2 on the same network interface as that of pc1 instead of localhost.

Comment: Thank You Akshit, But that only solved my one problem. Before when I use localhost nothing was happening but after replacing the private IP of pc2 with localhost, the request goes to the PHP server rather than the nodejs server. @AkshitGrover

Comment: I am not sure what is the setup you are trying to build.
I also missed the part where you mentioned that nginx server is running on pc2, In this case it should work with localhost as well since localhost is nothing but a DN of 127.0.0.1
My question is if you are redirecting requests coming to apache then why do you need it in the first place. Some clarity would be appreciated.

Comment: I am just trying to see how reverse proxy works. This is just a demo and I want to test it between 2 pcs of the same network. On the same PC it worked but in 2 different machines, it is not working.